# Ball rolling to the right only?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been experimenting with creating a bouncing ball animation. While most aspects of the coding have been okay,

I've encountered a peculiar issue that has left me scratching my head. I've managed to get the ball to bounce, but for some reason, it seems to only roll to the right until it collides with the right side of the viewport.

I'm really confused, and I'm eager to delve deeper into understanding what might be causing this unexpected behavior and how I can rectify it.

Here's the snippet of my JavaScript file:

```js
var ball = document.querySelector('.ball'),
    isDragging = false,
    isAnimating = false,
    isAnimationAllowed = true, // New flag to control animation while dragging
    offsetX,
    offsetY,
    velocityX = 0,
    velocityY = 0,
    friction = 0.95,
    gravity = 0.5,
    floorLevel = 500,
    animationFrame;

ball.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragging);
ball.addEventListener('touchstart', startDragging);

function startDragging(event) {
    isDragging = true;
    isAnimating = false; // Reset isAnimating to false
    isAnimationAllowed = false; // Disable animation while dragging
    offsetX = event.clientX - ball.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    offsetY = event.clientY - ball.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging);
    
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', drag);
    document.addEventListener('touchend', stopDragging);
  }

function drag(event) {
  if (!isDragging) return;

  event.preventDefault();

  var newX, newY;

  if (event.type === 'mousemove') {
    newX = event.clientX - offsetX;
    newY = event.clientY - offsetY;
  } else if (event.type === 'touchmove') {
    newX = event.touches[0].clientX - offsetX;
    newY = event.touches[0].clientY - offsetY;
  }

  ball.style.left = newX + "px";
  ball.style.top = newY + "px";

  velocityX = newX - ball.offsetLeft;
  velocityY = newY - ball.offsetTop;
}

function stopDragging() {
  isDragging = false;
  isAnimationAllowed = true; // Enable animation after dragging stops

  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging);

  document.removeEventListener('touchmove', drag);
  document.removeEventListener('touchend', stopDragging);

  if (!isAnimating) {
    animate();
  }
}

function animate() {
  if (!isAnimationAllowed) return; // Check if animation is allowed
  
  isAnimating = true;

  animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  velocityX *= friction;
  velocityY += gravity;

  var newX = ball.offsetLeft + velocityX;
  var newY = ball.offsetTop + velocityY;

  if (newY >= floorLevel - ball.offsetHeight) {
    newY = floorLevel - ball.offsetHeight;
    velocityY *= -0.6; // Bounce effect
  }

  if (newX < 0) {
    newX = 0;
    velocityX *= -0.6; // Bounce effect for the left boundary
  } else if (newX > window.innerWidth - ball.offsetWidth) {
    newX = window.innerWidth - ball.offsetWidth;
    velocityX *= -0.6; // Bounce effect for the right boundary
  }

  ball.style.left = newX + "px";
  ball.style.top = newY + "px";

  if (Math.abs(velocityX) < 0.1 && Math.abs(velocityY) < 0.1 && newY >= floorLevel - ball.offsetHeight) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrame);
    isAnimating = false;
  }
}
```

```css
div.ball {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 65% 15%, white 1px, aqua 3%, darkblue 60%, aqua 100%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

Comment: I've created a run-able snippet. Please review and make edits if needed

Comment: I can't see the ball rolling to the right. It just bounces and maintains the same X coordinates. Can you please provide more specifications?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the value of `velocityX` and `velocityY` when you first call `stopDragging()` you will notice that they are always `0`. This is because the following two lines in `drag(event)` are not working properly:

```
  velocityX = newX - ball.offsetLeft;
  velocityY = newY - ball.offsetTop;
```

It appears that `newX` and `ball.offsetLeft` have the same value, so there is something wrong with your logic there.

So, I replaced these two lines with (dividing by 10 just to lower the speed):

```
  velocityX = newX / 10;
  velocityY = newY / 10;
```

And we can now see the effect that you are describing, namely that the ball is always rolling off to the right after you release it, irrespective of whether you were dragging left or right at the time.

Now, if you make `velocityX` negative, for example:

```
  velocityX = - newX / 10;
```

then you will notice that the ball will always roll to the left. So the problem is here.

Please therefore study how I have altered `drag(event)` by introducing the variables `oldX` and `oldY` to keep track of the previous coordinates of the location of the ball.

You may also want to read up about the [`movementX` property of `MouseEvent` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/movementX) as that might be interesting for you too.

I set the `floorlevel` to 400 so that the ball is visible most of the time in Snack Code Snippet.

```js
var ball = document.querySelector('.ball'),
  isDragging = false,
  isAnimating = false,
  isAnimationAllowed = true, // New flag to control animation while dragging
  offsetX,
  offsetY,
  velocityX = 0,
  velocityY = 0,
  friction = 0.95,
  gravity = 0.5,
  floorLevel = 400,
  animationFrame;

let newX, newY;

ball.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragging);
ball.addEventListener('touchstart', startDragging);

function startDragging(event) {
  isDragging = true;
  isAnimating = false; // Reset isAnimating to false
  isAnimationAllowed = false; // Disable animation while dragging
  offsetX = event.clientX - ball.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  offsetY = event.clientY - ball.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging);

  document.addEventListener('touchmove', drag);
  document.addEventListener('touchend', stopDragging);
}

function drag(event) {
  if (!isDragging) return;

  event.preventDefault();

  let oldX = newX;
  let oldY = newY;

  if (event.type === 'mousemove') {
    newX = event.clientX - offsetX;
    newY = event.clientY - offsetY;
  } else if (event.type === 'touchmove') {
    newX = event.touches[0].clientX - offsetX;
    newY = event.touches[0].clientY - offsetY;
  }

  let directionX = Math.sign(newX - oldX);
  let directionY = Math.sign(newY - oldY);

  ball.style.left = newX + "px";
  ball.style.top = newY + "px";

  velocityX = directionX * newX / 10;
  velocityY = directionY * newY / 10;
}

function stopDragging() {
  isDragging = false;
  isAnimationAllowed = true; // Enable animation after dragging stops

  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag);
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging);

  document.removeEventListener('touchmove', drag);
  document.removeEventListener('touchend', stopDragging);

  if (!isAnimating) {
    animate();
  }
}

function animate() {
  if (!isAnimationAllowed) return; // Check if animation is allowed

  isAnimating = true;

  animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  velocityX *= friction;
  velocityY += gravity;

  var newX = ball.offsetLeft + velocityX;
  var newY = ball.offsetTop + velocityY;

  if (newY >= floorLevel - ball.offsetHeight) {
    newY = floorLevel - ball.offsetHeight;
    velocityY *= -0.6; // Bounce effect
  }

  if (newX < 0) {
    newX = 0;
    velocityX *= -0.6; // Bounce effect for the left boundary
  } else if (newX > window.innerWidth - ball.offsetWidth) {
    newX = window.innerWidth - ball.offsetWidth;
    velocityX *= -0.6; // Bounce effect for the right boundary
  }

  ball.style.left = newX + "px";
  ball.style.top = newY + "px";

  if (Math.abs(velocityX) < 0.1 && Math.abs(velocityY) < 0.1 && newY >= floorLevel - ball.offsetHeight) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrame);
    isAnimating = false;
  }
}
```

```css
div.ball {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 65% 15%, white 1px, aqua 3%, darkblue 60%, aqua 100%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```